# Insert into temp table based on rows already in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, insert

I am building a temp table #Table that contains different Categories, Items, and Costs.

For example:

```
Category    Item    Cost
--------    ----    ----
Office      Desk    100.00
Office      Chair   75.00
Office      PC      800.00
Home        Desk    0.00
```

At the time that I receive the temp table for my processing, there are the individual rows with Category, Item, and Cost as well as Summary rows that contain the sum of each category that has a non-zero total:

```
Category    Item    Cost    Type
--------    ----    ----    -----
Office      Desk    100.00  Cost
Office      Chair   75.00   Cost
Office      PC      800.00  Cost
Office      null    975.00  Summary
Home        Desk    0.00    Cost
```

I would like to add summary rows for the $0.00 cost rows now as well, but am having trouble with figuring out how to do so.

```
INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT X.Category, null, 0.00, 'Summary'
FROM #Table X
...[Get Category data that does not have a Summary row]
```

I had thought about

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #Table Y WHERE Y.Category = X.Category AND Type = 'Summary')
GROUP BY X.Category
```

but am concerned about performance, as there could be a lot of rows in this table.

Comment: If you're concerned about perf, post the execution plan. How long does it take and how low do you need it?

Comment: Please clarify. You want to insert the category from #table to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should benchmark your performance, but I've found joins are faster. Also, if your dataset it very large, adding an index after the data is loaded into the temp table can dramatically speed up subsequent table queries.

```
INSERT INTO #Table
   SELECT X.Category, null, 0.00, 'Summary'
   FROM #Table X
   LEFT JOIN #Table Y ON Y.Category = X.Category AND Y.Type = 'Summary'
   WHERE Y.Category IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this in 2 steps -

1 - Insert the raw data straight away - without summary info
2 - Insert more data - SELECT data grouping by Category, using SUM aggregate on cost, and hard coding NULL for Item & SUMMARY for Type field.